# Creating own module

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Please help me with this simple question

> In the exercise, we already have the main program in the module, which is as follows:

```
    
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

import mymodule

mymodule.printme("Exampleline")
```

> The objective is to implement this mymodule-module applied in the exercise. Create a module, which has a function printme, which prints the given parameter with the disclaimer "I got:" and after that, "The parameter was [length] characters long." When the module is implemented correctly, the program prints out the following:

```
>>> 

I got: Exampleline
The parameter was 11 characters long.
>>>
```

> *Example output:*

```
I got: Exampleline
The parameter was 11 characters long.
```

And here is **my output**:

```
import mymodule
def main():
    n=mymodule.printme
    m=len(n)
    print("I got: ",n)
    print("The parameter was ",m,"characters long.")
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Honestly, I didn't really comprehend what the exercise is demanding. Therefore, I need help from all of you. And below is the interpreter's report:

> File "ohjelma.py", line 5, in 
> mymodule.printme("Exampleline")
> AttributeError: module 'mymodule' has no attribute 'printme'

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tangentially, maybe ask your professor why you are not using UTF-8 for all your source files.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a module very easily. It's just another file.

The easiest way to do this is to create the mymodule.py file.
And in the mymodule.py file, you will need a function.

```
# mymodule.py
def printme(string):
    print('I got: {0}'.format(string))
    print('The parameter was {} characters long.'.format(len(string))
```

Then you can import it just like in the example, and run the `printme` function.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't comprehend all. Could you please help me based on the what given by the exercise???

Comment: @DanhNguyễn Did you try it? This is the solution to the exercise given.

Answer (score 1):

In that exercise you are writing INSIDE mymodule.py. Your goal is to write printme function in that mymodule, so that when the main module imports this mymodule and calls the function printme, the example output is produced.

This one worked for me:

```
def printme(text):
    print("I got:",text)
    print("The parameter was",len(text),"characters long.")
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def printme(sth):
    print("I got:",(sth))
    print("The parameter was",len(sth),"characters long.")
```

Try this, it works

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.